# Equate two HashMap based on certain keys only

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, field, selected

I need to determine equality of two HashMaps based on few keys only (not all)

other than by individually accessing each field and comparing for equality, is there any time efficient method to do this?

Comment: so far my attempt has been extract my required fields and compare each of them

Comment: because I need to compare for very large number, I wanted to know if there is any efficient mechanism to achieve this

Comment: how you wanna select 'few' key? any pattern or random?

Comment: I will have a list of selected keys

Comment: You want to check only if the keys are present or you want to check if the values in the Keys were also equal or not?

Comment: check code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One method I can think of is to store some sort of a 'compressed label' on your HashMap that gets updated everytime a new item is added / existing item is modified / deleted. Whenever you need to do a comparison, you just compare this 'compressed label'.

I'm not sure what kind of algorithm to use for this 'compressed label'. If all your HashMap items can be transformed intro a String, you can try MD5 hash all the concatenation of the string maybe?

Ofcourse doing this has the drawback of added burden of having to calculate the the 'compressed label' each time you modify the HashMap elements.

The idea is similar like how you use a .md5 file to verify the downloaded file is consistent (no corruption due to network transfer). I'm not sure though whether it'll work in your case / not

Answer (score 0):

```
so far my attempt has been extract my required fields and compare each of them
```

As per my knowledge this is the best way

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of keys, this should be efficient enough. as `hashmap.get()` is already optimized internally

```
public boolean isNotEqual(){
boolean unequal = false;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
if(ob1.containsKey(list.elementAt(i)) && ob2.containsKey(list.elementAt(i))){
    if(!ob1.equals(ob2)) {
        unequal = true;
        break;
}else{
    unequal = true;
    break;
}
return unequal;
}
```

Comment: yes this exactly what I have been doing. But the thing is I have millions of such hash map, now doing so in such huge data is time consuming. So I just wanted to know if there is better solution

Comment: yes there could be a better solution, like writing your own optimized hash-algo with some other data structure, but as you are using HashMap it is default optimized. So anything additional will only reduce the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any way of predicting how the sets of keys for which you'll need to be comparing equality will be composed? If so, you could construct submaps corresponding to each of those sets of keys and then use simple .equals() on those submaps, which may be worth it if you're doing a lot more equality comparisons than puts in the master map. Otherwise, I'm not sure if there's a faster solution than brute force checking.